# Find whether a raw in data table contains at least one word from the list

Tags: r, datatable

I am quite new to R and data tables, so probably my question will sound obvious, but I searched through questions here for similar issues and couldn't find a solution anyway.

So, initially, I have a data table and one of the rows contains fields that have many values(in fact these values are all separate words) of the data joined together by &&&&. I also have a list of words (list). This list is big and has 38 000 different words. But for the purpose of example let's sat that it is small.

list <- c('word1', 'word2, 'word3')

What I need is to filter the data table so that I only have rows that contain at least one word from the list of words.

I unjoined the data by &&&&& and created a list

fields_with_words <-strsplit(data_final$fields_with_words,"&&&&")

But I don't know which function should I use to check whether the row from my data table has at least one word from the list. Can you give me some clues?

Comment: See `match` or `%in%`, i.e. `fields_with_words %in% list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
data_final[sapply(strsplit(data_final$fields_with_words,"&&&&"), function(x) 
                  any(x %in% word_list)), ]
```

I have used `word_list` instead of `list` here since `list` is a built-in function in R.

Comment: Thank you! It worked,took some time,but it is a relief that it worked

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to scan `x` variable in `df` with the list of words `lw <- c("word1","word2","word3")` (character vector of words), you can use

```r
df[grepl(paste0("(",paste(lw, collapse = "|"), ")"), x)]
```

if you want regular expression. In particular you will have match also if your word is within a sentence. However, with 38k words, I don't know if this solution is scalable.

If your `x` column contains only words and you want exact matching, the problem is simpler. You can do:

```r
df[any(x %chin% lw)]
```

`%chin%` is a `data.table` special `%in%` operator for character vectors (`%in%` can also be used but it will not be as performant). You can have better performance there if you use `merge` by transforming `lw` into a `data.table`:

```r
merge(df, data.table(x = lw), by = "x")
```